# In Javascript, how to convert a string to a property name?

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties

I have a global object with various properties whose values are strings. When a user types a string into an HTML input, I'm using javascript to assign that string to a variable. I need to convert that string to a property name and return the string associated with that property.

For example:

```
myglobalobject = {

    propertyname : "String value to be returned."

}

function GetInput(){
    mystring = document.getElementById('input').value;

    myproperty = convertstringToProperty(str); //This is where I need a solution

    return myglobalobject.myproperty;
}
```

Comment: Directly use `myglobalobject[mystring]`. You dont need to convert anything.

Comment: `myGlobalObj[str]`

Comment: Facepalm. If it was a snake it would have bitten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a computed property:

```
return myglobalobject[mystring];
```

This is a generalization of the fact that property accesses using dot notation are the same as accessing with brackets and a string literal:

```
obj.prop === obj["prop"];
```

So when you have something that isn't a string literal, just use the bracket notation.

Answer (score 3):

Well, properties can be accessed with, you guess it, a string:

```js
const myObject = {
  property1: 0,
  property2: 1,
};

const inputFromUser = 'property1';
console.log(myObject[inputFromUser]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a function:

```js
var myglobalobject = {
    propertyname : "String value to be returned."
}
function GetInput(){
    mystring = 'anotherKey';

    return myglobalobject[mystring] = undefined;
}
GetInput()
console.log(myglobalobject)
```